# why url cannot be generated after use blueprint

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

My current project looks like this:

```
├── __init__.py
├── pages
├── settings.py
├── static
├── templates
│   ├── article.html
│   ├── base.html
│   ├── index.html
│   └── posts.html
├── view
│   ├── article.py
│   ├── home.py
│   ├── index.py
│   └── postwall.py
```

I breaked views.py(no longer in the project) into files and those files cannot generate url dynamically anymore. What i had in article.py is:

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template
from app import articles
article = Blueprint('article',__name__)

@article.route('/article/<path:path>/')
def page(path):
    article = articles.get_or_404(path)
    return render_template('article.html',page=article)
```

Meanwhile, posts.html which offers the link button to articles doesn't work anymore:

```
<a href="{{ url_for('page', path=page.path) }}">More -></a>
```

What is the problem?Did I miss something in the blueprint file?

Answer (score 2):

solved. change

```
<a href="{{ url_for('page', path=page.path) }}">More -></a>
```

to

```
<a href="{{ url_for('article.page', path=page.path) }}">More -></a>
```

forgot to add blueprint name